# What is -- and -td options on ls command?

Tags: command-line, ls, options

Could you please explain what each option on this `ls` command does: `ls -td -- */`?
The result of such command would look like below:

```
$ ls
$ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   68 Jun  4 09:58 .
drwxrwxrwt. 13 root root 4096 Jun  4 10:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   36 May 31 15:48 05-31-2018
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   36 Jun  4 09:45 06-04-2018
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Jun  4 09:56 06-05-2018
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jun  4 09:58 test

$  ls -td -- */ 
06-05-2018/  06-04-2018/  05-31-2018/

# To get latest folder created:
$ ls -td -- */ | head -n 1
06-05-2018/
```

I have no ideas what each option would do with `ls` command.

Comment: `-td` is two options: `-t` and `-d`. Check your `ls` man page for their meanings. `--` indicates the end of the options. This is useful to prevent any filenames that happen to begin with a hyphen from affecting `ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-td` is the two options `-t` and `-d` written together. `-t` tells `ls` to sort the output based on time, and `-d` asks to show directories named on the command line as themselves, instead of their contents.

The **`--`** option is as far as I know not explicitly documented for many commands that do support it and it has become a slightly obscure syntax.
It finds it's origins in the [`getopt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) function and is use to *delimit the end of the options and the start of the parameters*.

You would mainly use that `--` syntax to use parameters that would otherwise look like options.

A good illustration is trying to manipulate files that start their names with a hyphen such as a file called `"-rm -rf"`

Create it with `touch -- '-rm -rf'`

```
ls -la
total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 herman  wheel    0 Jun  4 16:46 -rm -rf

ls -la *
ls: illegal option --
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

ls -la -- * 
total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 herman  wheel    0 Jun  4 16:46 -rm -rf
```

and

```
rm -i *
rm: illegal option -- m
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

versus

```
rm -i -- *
```

---

For the meaning of command line options in general, this very basic nugget:

Nearly all Linux commands come with an online manual explaining their usage and various options that modify their behaviour. Than manual can be accessed with the `man` command i.e.

[`man ls`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)

Try [`man man`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/man) for an explanation of the manual.

Comment: You also use `--` when you _don't know_ whether the names may start with `-` as in `ls -d -- *` or `ls -d -- "$1"`. A more striking example is with a file called `-r` with `rm`. Where a `rm *` can become a `rm -r *` and end up deleting a lot more than intended.

Comment: I'm a bit tempted to change the example to something other than `-rf` (though the preceding space should cause an error in any case.)